# Partition issue on upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 from 16.10

Tags: boot, partitioning

My upgrade to 17.04 from 16.10 fails.

My existing 16.10 is on a 750 HDD, installed on a 105 GB partition /dev/sdc1.  It has a 32GB swap partition on it at /dev/sdc2

I bought a new SSD 250GB, and used gparted to create 108 GB partition on it at /dev/sdd1.  Also a /dev/sdd2 spap partition of 32GB.

Used Clonezilla to copy partition /dev/sdc1 to /dev/sdd1.

I tried to boot, but failed as there was no MBR.

I used dd if=dev/sdc of=dev/sdd bs=512 count=1 to copy the MBR from existing 16.10 /dev/sdc HDD to what will become new 17.04 on /dev/sdd SSD (it had 16.10 on it after clonezilla image copy).

I removed HDD /dev/sdc from the system to prevent UUID same issues.

This booted, and I ran it for a day to ensure it was working OK.  It did.  So next day, I started the upgrade to 17.04.

This failed. Reset to image via clonezilla multiple times, trying multiple approaches - all failed.

Using livecd, gparted, found the new 250GB SSD was showing it was 750GB and causing errors, which it should, since this was a 250GB drive.

I redid the partitions using gparted, reinstalled 16.10 with same results.  When I create the partitions on the new SSD, they are 108GB (OS), 32GB (swap), 110 GB (free or unused).

But after each failed attempt, gparted is showing the free or unused has been set as though the SSD is 750 GB!  In other words, the SSD free somehow goes from 110 GB (free or unused) to 610 GB (free or unused) and then everything fails.

**Any ideas as to how I can prevent this from happening?**

Comment: If you use `gparted` to lay down a fresh msdos partition table, then create your partitions, then clonezilla over the partition data, I think that'll work. Why so large a swap partition?

Comment: ps: You'll probably have to manually install GRUB, or use boot-repair to finish the job. I'm assuming this is an older BIOS computer, not a newer UEFI computer... if not, then things change.

Comment: heynnema, the swap partition I created was 32GB, which is twice my memory of 16GB.  See above.  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: 32G swap is WAY excessive for 16G RAM. You could easily run with a 8G swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if  under stand correctly, you are copying from a 750 GB to a 250 GB?

when you copy the MBR it copies the reported size in the MBR.

he's what I'd do since you have a second working Ubuntu.

1) reformat the drive so you get the right space indication, and make your partition. (you might need to do this on windows so the MBR gets wiped)

2) copy your partition with clonezilla. boot into your working ubuntu, then connect the new drive. Use gparted to change uuid, and edit /etc/fstab of the copy to reflect the change.

3) update grub to get a grub entry for the new ubuntu. boot into the new ubuntu using the grub of the old ubuntu

4) once in the new, update initramfs, then install and update grub.

Comment: ravery, thanks for your response; understand it's the copied MBR that is the issue and that makes sense.  Regarding item 3) above - will that step create a new MBR?  Also, in 4) not familiar with 'initramfs' so don't know how to update or why necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: yes the copied MBR is the problem. you could try just wiping the MBR with some utility. then jump to step 3